Как мне реализовать данную функцию?
Мне нужно сделать своеобразную проверку на жанры. То есть у меня есть база данных, которая содержит в себе какую-то информацию о книге по ее индексу. Я выбираю какое-то рандомное число, нахожу эту книгу в базе данных по индексу, проверяю есть ли в ней необходимые мне жанры, и если нет, то функция запускается по новой уже с другим числом. Когда такая книга находится, то нужно выводить какую-либо информацию о ней, но это уже не так важно
conn = sqlite3.connect('booksrec.db')
curs = conn.cursor()

my_genres = ['Historical', 'Fantasy', 'Business']
number_of_books = random.randint(0, 9999)

def kniga(number):
    curs.execute(f'SELECT * FROM books WHERE "index" = "{number_of_books}"')
    book = curs.fetchone()
    for element in my_genres:
        if element in book[5]:
            print(book[2])
        else:
            kniga(random.randint(0, 9999))

kniga(number_of_books)

При таком написании вылезает ошибка о превышении глубины рекурсии. Что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

book[5] является в данном коде списком жанров из таблицы, а book[2] необходимая для вывода информация

Какой-то странный подход, честно говоря.... Вы понимаете, сколько можно выбирать таким образом книгу? Если у вас книг, подходящих под условия всего 10 на 10000 например, так можно долго выбирать, особенно если учитывать, что рандомные числа могут повторяться. Неудивительно, что вы словили ошибку по рекурсии. Не легче ли сразу дернуть книги по жанрам, а потом уже из них выбрать рандомную?

Параметр number не используется в функции kniga, что приводит к бесконечной выборке одной и той же книги. Не надо использовать глобальные переменные. Надо использовать отладчик. Отладчик гораздо лучше глобальных переменных.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries

Ну избавиться то от рекурсии легко:
def kniga(number):
    while True:
        number_of_books = random.randint(0, 9999)
        curs.execute(f'SELECT * FROM books WHERE "index" = "{number_of_books}"')
        book = curs.fetchone()
        found = True
        for element in my_genres:
            if element not in book[5]:
                found = False
                break
        if found:
            print(book[2])
            break

Но подход изначально порочный. Вы можете много раз выбирать одни и те же книги на проверку. И зря будете дёргать базу, если нужных книг там немного. Лучше всё-таки придумать, как вынуть из базы только подходящие по критерию книги и из них уже выбрать одну случайную.
P.S. Переделал проверку на более правильную, если нужны все три жанра. Если достаточно совпадения одного жанра из списка, проверку нужно будет переделать.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries
